# Why are my soil sensor outputs starting correct, but turning into nonsense?

Tags: arduino, sensor, i2c, library, soil-sensing

I have two Adafruit STEMMA Soil Sensors [STEMMA Soil Sensors](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4026) that I've hooked up to an Arduino nano, telling a solenoid valve when to open. I also have a rain sensor and photoresistor to determine the watering frequency, which work as intended.

The sensors work through I2C communication. Since they can only take on 5 different addresses, and I want to use up to 8 sensors, I purchased a [TCA I2C Multiplexer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2717) to plug the soil sensor inputs into.

The sensors return a capacitive value between 200 and 2000, depending on the moisture of the soil. Here is my code that I believe is giving me problems:

```
 * TCA9548 I2CScanner.ino -- I2C bus scanner for Arduino
 *
 * Based on https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/
 * 
 * Sketch to read Serial outputs for testing purposes 
 *
 */

#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_seesaw.h"

//soil sensor 
Adafruit_seesaw ss;
#define numSensors 2
uint8_t relayPin = 15;

//multiplexer address
#define TCAADDR 0x70

//select tca port to communicate with
void tcaselect(uint8_t addr) {
  if (addr > 7) return;
 
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << addr);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
}

//initialize output pins 
void initOutputPins() {
  for (int i = 5; i <= (numSensors + 4); i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

//Finds active ports and connected I2C addresses 
void findActivePorts() {
  
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++) {
      tcaselect(i);
      Serial.print("TCA Port #"); Serial.println(i);

      for (uint8_t addr = 0; addr <= 127; addr++) {
          if (addr == TCAADDR) continue;

          Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
            if (!Wire.endTransmission()) {
             Serial.print("Found soil sensor at 0x");  Serial.println(addr,HEX);
           }
      }
      
    }
}

//use photoresistor to determine water frequncy - removed for readability 
uint16_t getTimeToCheck() {

  return timeToCheck;
}

//removed for readability 
bool checkIsRaining() {

  return isRaining; 
}

//removed for readability 
uint16_t getTimeToWater() {

  return timeToWater;
}


// standard setup
void setup() {

    //initialize outputs
    initOutputPins();  
  
    //begin Serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    delay(1000);

    //initialize Wire and sensor objects
    Wire.begin();
    ss.begin(0x36);

    pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
    
    Serial.println("\nTCAScanner ready.");
    Serial.println("Soil Sensor(s) ready");

    //Find connected I2C addresses
    findActivePorts(); 
    
    Serial.println("\ndone");
    
}

void loop() 
{

  bool isRaining = checkIsRaining();
  uint16_t timeToWater = getTimeToWater();
  uint16_t timeToCheck = getTimeToCheck();

  if(!isRaining) {

      for (uint8_t x = 0; x <= (numSensors - 1); x++) {
        uint8_t pinNum = x + 5;
        digitalWrite(pinNum, HIGH);
        Serial.println("Sensor ON");
        delay(100);
        tcaselect(x);
        delay(100);
    
        float temp = ss.getTemp();
        delay(100);
        uint16_t capread = ss.touchRead(0);
        delay(100);
      
        Serial.print("Sensor "); Serial.print(x + 1); Serial.print(" Capacitive: "); Serial.println(capread);
        Serial.print("Sensor "); Serial.print(x + 1); Serial.print(" Temperature: "); Serial.println(temp);
    
        if(capread < 1200) {
           digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
           Serial.println("Valve Open");
           delay(timeToWater);
           digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
           Serial.println("Valve Closed");
           delay(10000);
         }else {
           
         }
    
        digitalWrite(pinNum, LOW);
        Serial.println("Sensor OFF");
        delay(timeToCheck);
    
      }
   }
   delay(1000);
}
```

The meat of the photcell/rain sensor functions have been removed for ease of readability. The soil sensors are only turned on when they are reading soil values.

When I run this code, the first sensor (connected to SDA/SCL ports "0") returns a proper capacitive value/temperature, maybe 500 for capacitive and 30.2 Celcius for the temperature. This is correct - I know that the values are legitimate and in the working range.

However, when the for loop goes through the second sensor, it returns a capacitive value of 65535 and ~400 degrees, both of which are obviously wrong/out of the expected value range. When the for loop begins again and starts at the first sensor, the first sensor now returns nonsense values of 65535 capacitance and 400+ degrees. It keeps returning these nonsense values for both sensors for as long as I run it.

I know that these sensors work on their own - but I'm not sure why it screws up on the loop. My guess is that, by looping through, something is not initialized correctly each time the sensor is read. A few thoughts:

- Could this have to do with the "begin()" function?
- Could this have to do with the "touchRead()" function? This is the .cpp file in the library:

```
 ******************************************************************************
 *  @brief      read the analog value on an capacitive touch-enabled pin.
 *
 *  @param      pin the number of the pin to read.
 *
 *  @return     the analog value. This is an integer between 0 and 1023
 ****************************************************************************/
uint16_t Adafruit_seesaw::touchRead(uint8_t pin) {
  uint8_t buf[2];
  uint8_t p = pin;
  uint16_t ret = 65535;

  for (uint8_t retry = 0; retry < 5; retry++) {
    if (this->read(SEESAW_TOUCH_BASE, SEESAW_TOUCH_CHANNEL_OFFSET + p, buf, 2,
                   3000 + retry * 1000)) {
      ret = ((uint16_t)buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

It's returning what ret is initialized to at first - 65535. Can someone explain what is going on inside the for loop?

- Sometimes, the isRaining variable turns true, even though the sensor is not outputting a HIGH digital signal. This leads me to believe that there may be some interference/mix up between variables and things in the code.

I know that this is a lot, but I have no idea what to do. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can't turn the sensors OF then ON and not initialize them ...and that appears to be what you do.

Comment: @jackcreasey --  What init are you talking about?  I only see Arduino pin state changed to OUTPUT and never set to another state, in which case we don't have to reinitialize. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you draw us a schematic, including the multiplexer? Also,  Please make sure your info is complete. Specifically, where is ss assigned? Finally, I see an ss.begin() -- should there be an ss.end()?

Comment: can you use another Wire instance on a different set of pins to kill that extra multiplexer complexity?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD ...look for "Sensor On" and "Sensor Off", the OP may be turning the individual sensors on/off (maybe it's just a LED indicator). However, the OP does not appear to init 8 sensors ....see: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Seesaw/blob/master/examples/soil_sensor/soilsensor_example/soilsensor_example.ino

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Here is a [schematic](https://github.com/Markahofmeister/ShowHerb/blob/main/media/images/Schematic.jpg). In terms of "end," I'm not sure that I can; there doesn't seem to be a function in the Adafruit_seesaw library that does so. And I am turning the sensors "ON" and "OFF" - I cut their 5V supply unless they are being used. This is to extend their life. However, I've tested with them connected to a constant 5V supply, so I'm not sure this is the issue.

Comment: @dandavis can you explain what you mean? If I understand you, you're saying to hook up to another set of SDA/SCL ports on the Arduino...which can't be done, there's only one set. And they are both on different busses from the multiplexer.

Comment: interesting, on the 8266 they can be re-assigned somewhat arbitrarily, since it doesn't have hardware i2c anyway. But you could use software i2c on the nano, i think, something like https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/softwarewire/

Comment: A datasheet is a sea of information that you will soon learn to navigate. Your multiplexer has pins that must be connected, one way or the other, that you have left open, the A1 and A2 pins, and the Reset pin.  Also, you are supposed to bypass the ic with a capacitor, and I don't know if layout guidelines are tripping you up. It would be good for you to look at your signals with an oscilloscope. Also, even though you think of your Arduino as a black box, it too has a datasheet, and the maximums and guidelines are also rules you have to follow with consequences if you break them. Read. Read...

Comment: @MarkHofmeister You canot turn the sensor OFF and ON when need. They must be powered ALL the time. The sensor is a small MCU (the SeeSaw) that must be initialized.